keycloak import realm docker-compose
this is my docker compose of the keycloaks part, but the import is not being made.
|-project
  |-imports/realm-export.json
  |-docker-compose.yml

this is my tree file
keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:25.0.2
    command:
      - "start-dev"
      - "--import-realm"
      - "--http-port=8070"
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=/opt/keycloak/data/imports/realm-export.json
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - KEYCLOAK_IMPORT_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
    volumes:
      - ./imports/realm-export.json:/opt/keycloak/imports/realm-export.json
    ports:
      - 8070:8070


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In the guide page https://www.keycloak.org/server/importExport#_importing_a_realm_during_startup, the import directory is /opt/keycloak/data/import (notice the "import" has no "s"). Just put the realm export file there and Keycloak will load it up. Make sure your volume path is correct (you are missing "data" directory in the path in your docker-compose script).
The usage of environment variable KEYCLOAK_IMPORT has been removed since Keycloak 17.
